# Getting Image from user class in Parse

Tags: android, image, parse-platform

I am trying to get a file (profile Image) from the user class in Parse.
This is the code that I am trying to but I am getting the following error, where am I going wrong?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        navigationItemsList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        addItemsToNavigationList();


        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mAdapter = new com.charity.dogood.dogood.adapters.NavDrawerAdapter(navigationItemsList, this, HEADER_NAME, HEADER_EMAIL, HEADER_IMAGE);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        //Parse Image and details of the logged in user
        // Locate the class table named "ImageUpload" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("User");
        Log.d("Mainactivity", "After query 1");

        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        Log.d("Mainactivity", "After query 2");
        query.whereEqualTo("username", currentUser);
        Log.d("Mainactivity", "After query 3");
        // String usernam = (String)currentUser;

        if(currentUser != null){
            Log.d("Mainactivity", "came to current user check statement");
        query.getInBackground(currentUser.getUsername().toString(), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {

                ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object.get("ImageProfile");

                fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome Back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                            // HEADER_IMAGE image = (ImageView) fin
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                            builder.setTitle("Sorry");
                            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });
            Log.d("Mainactivity", "After query 4");
    }
```

ERROR

```
07-17 14:11:40.030: D/Mainactivity(3857): After query 1
07-17 14:11:40.030: D/Mainactivity(3857): After query 2
07-17 14:11:40.030: D/Mainactivity(3857): After query 3
07-17 14:11:40.030: D/Mainactivity(3857): came to current user check statement
07-17 14:11:40.030: D/Mainactivity(3857): After query 4
07-17 14:11:40.120: V/WindowManager(463): Adding window Window{267de77b u0 com.charity.dogood.dogood/com.charity.dogood.dogood.activities.MainActivity} at 3 of 9 (after Window{3da1ef5a u0 com.charity.dogood.dogood/com.charity.dogood.dogood.activities.Login})
07-17 14:11:40.220: W/EGL_emulation(3857): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-17 14:11:40.220: W/OpenGLRenderer(3857): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa207d700, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-17 14:11:40.276: I/ActivityManager(463): Displayed com.charity.dogood.dogood/.activities.MainActivity: +283ms
07-17 14:11:40.421: D/AndroidRuntime(3857): Shutting down VM
07-17 14:11:40.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 14:11:40.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3857): Process: com.charity.dogood.dogood, PID: 3857
07-17 14:11:40.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3857): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object com.parse.ParseObject.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
07-17 14:11:40.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at com.charity.dogood.dogood.activities.MainActivity$1.done(MainActivity.java:104)
07-17 14:11:40.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at com.charity.dogood.dogood.activities.MainActivity$1.done(MainActivity.java:99)
07-17 14:11:40.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:944)
07-17 14:11:40.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-17 14:11:40.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-17 14:11:40.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-17 14:11:40.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-17 14:11:40.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-17 14:11:40.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-17 14:11:40.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-17 14:11:40.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3857):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

UPDATED:

```
 @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {


                ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object.get("ImageProfile");


                if(fileObject != null) {
                    fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome Back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                                // HEADER_IMAGE image = (ImageView) fin
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                                builder.setTitle("Sorry");
                                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                    builder.setTitle("Sorry");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();

                }
```

Comment: You should probably add a null check for `object` and use `e.getMessage()` to get the error.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, `object` will be null if the query failed https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/GetCallback.html   So, definitely add a null check in `done(ParseObject object, ParseException e)`, just as you have for `done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e)`.

Comment: @DanielNugent please see updated code, but still getting error.

Comment: You need to check `if (object != null)` before you call `object.get()`, since that is what is causing the NPE.

Comment: yes now it tells me that no result for the query.. so that comes to my ultimate need how to get that column with the image?

Comment: @JackyBoi Yes, as expected, your query has no results.  As for figuring out why that is, check your data and make sure it has what you expect.  Something about your query or your data is not matching up.

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but to query users you should use `ParseUser.getQuery()`.

Comment: Guys it would be a great help if any of u could give me the proper code.
I basically have the user table with a column specifically for ImageProfile, which has images. I basically want to retrieve them that is all. Been trying for past 2hrs no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me given that the user has already logged in.

```
    private void setUserImage() {
    ImageView imgUser = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImage);
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            try {
                    ParseFile img = currentUser.getParseFile("userImage");
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img.getDataStream());
                    imgUser.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, buddy tks. But it is best not to answer old posts. But I am going to give this one to you. cheers!